# Create 2 child directories inside 3 different child directories

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to write a simple script that will create a folder and then 3 different folders inside and once that is done each of those 3 different folders should have 2 child folders named 'Phase' (1..2).

I'm trying to loop through the path, i.e the child folders (Project) but I don't know how to implement it, otherwise I can just write the last foreach loop another 3 times but that would be inconsistent.

The structure should be:

```
C:\Projects\Project1\Phase1
C:\Projects\Project1\Phase2
C:\Projects\Project2\Phase1
C:\Projects\Project2\Phase2
C:\Projects\Project3\Phase1
C:\Projects\Project3\Phase2
```

The script so far I've written is:

```
# Path variable 

$PhasePath = "C:\Projects\Project1"

# Creating the main directory
mkdir C:\Projects

# Loop from 1-3 and create a subdirectory in - Path C:\Projects using the path variable
1..3 | foreach $_{ New-Item -ItemType directory -Name $("Project" + $_) -Path C:\Projects } 

1..2 | foreach $_{ New-Item -ItemType directory -Name $("Phase" + $_) -Path $PhasePath }
```

Comment: Nest the second loop inside the first so it runs for every top level directory created.

Comment: @Tom So basically just pipe foreach | foreach or?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using the [instance method `CreateSubdirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.createsubdirectory?view=net-6.0#system-io-directoryinfo-createsubdirectory(system-string)) from the [`DirectoryInfo` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=net-6.0):

```bash
$initialPath = New-Item C:\Projects\ -ItemType Directory
1..3 | ForEach-Object {
    $sub  = $initialPath.CreateSubdirectory("Project$_")
    $null = 1..2 | ForEach-Object { $sub.CreateSubdirectory("Phase$_") }
}
```

Combining the interpolated paths is also an alternative using this method, similar to [ben's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73015019/15339544), though this might less readable:

```bash
$initialPath = New-Item .\Project -ItemType Directory
1..3 | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($i in 1..2) {
        $null = $initialPath.CreateSubdirectory("Project$_\Phase$i")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

this should do

```
foreach ($project in 1..3){foreach ($phase in 1..2) {new-item -Type Directory "C:\Projects\Project$($project)\Phase$($phase)"}}
```